# Reducing PDF size - From 5MB to ~200KB

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

## INTRO

[image: Original file size]

I have this 2,7 MB PDF file.

It's a certificate with two fields that I have to fill: name and course.

After filling those fields I save it for later printing.

## THE PROBLEM

After saving, the new file comes up with ~5MB.

[image: File size after saving]

I have tried many saving options and but I only managed to reduce it to the final size of 4,7MB (still larger than the original file).

For instance, I tried open the original file (2,7MB) and save it right after opening (without making any change). The result is the same: a new ~5MB file.

That means that it isn't the information (Name and Course) the faulty.

## SOLVING

[image: Low file size]

At some point, trying new methods of saving, I managed to save it to the size of 180KB.

Unfortunately, I'm not being able to reproduce this made.

After several hours trying to achieve this made again and not succeeding, I came here ask for help :(

Comment: Can you upload the PDF to test with? Try using Flate compression to compress the content streams. And are you looking for a programming solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

As you are in Acrobat, you might use "save as optimized…" (where you are already, in order to show the space usage), and remove as much as possible (mainly structure information, private data (which means data allowing the original-creating application to edit the file again), etc.).

You might also start from a minimum-sized blank file, and copy/paste the form fields into it. (although I don't think that would cause much reduction, as, AFAIK, fonts used in form fields are counted in the Fonts item).